# Generating non icon images

Tags: android, image, drawable

I want to add image resources to an Android app that won't be used for icons. I wanted to know what is the right way of doing it while supporting multiple device screen sizes. The only solution I can think of is resizing the image to different pixel (width, height) combinations and storing them in their appropriate drawable folders.
For images that are icons, I use the Android studio image asset tool to automatically generate different sized icons. I want that for images that are not icons(won't be placed in the toolbar and similar places).

**Solution that worked for me**

Used [Android Asset Studio, Generic Icon Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example)
to generate the resource images for the different device resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

1. Create folder `drawable-nodpi` and put your images inside it.
2. Use this code to find the width of the device:

---

```
public static int getWidth() {
    int width = 400;
    try {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) DataBackApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 12) {
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            width = size.x;
        } else {
            width = display.getWidth();  // Deprecated
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return width;
}
```

3. Build your layout.
4. Load image using this code:

---

```
int width = getWidth();
int imgWidth = width/6;
int imgHeight = width/9;
Glide.with(PermissionActivity.this)
        .load(R.drawable.privacy_mobile_img)
        .override(imgWidth, imgHeight )
        .into(imgUserPerm);
```

Use Glide to load the image because it will resize it for small, mid, or any size device. I used `width / 6` as an example, you can adjust as needed.